# show progress bar or loading image while running spd 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, designer-workflow, custom-list

I have a SP 2010 custom list which is fetching data from multiple lists. So I have written a workflow in SP Designer to get data (auto populate) from all lists.

It's working fine, but taking more than 30 seconds. While loading I need to display a progress bar (like gears).

If workflow status = null or in progress, I need to show status bar.

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you plan on checking the [if workflow status == null ] in the processing of the workflow itself?

Comment: Yes...if it is possible...but need to avoid the processing time and need to show something is happening in back end(loading symbol(gears)).

Comment: Did you find any solution of progress bar issue. I have similar requirement and looking for jquery or SP services solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a SPLongOperation class you can use.

[SPLongOperation Class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splongoperation%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

I would suggest that Workflows are typically for long-running, asynchronous tasks (that is, control is returned to the user via the GUI while workflow does its work), and that something like an event receiver is probably more suited to short tasks like yours. Using event receivers might not be available to you though.  If they are, I would look into creating a synchronous event receiver and using the SPLongOperation class.

Comment: Hey thanks for ur reply,I can't able to write custom server side code.Pls suggest me using jquery or sp services or ecma scripts code.